# Filtering and sorting with IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm looking for some suggestions in respect to how to filter and, simultaneously, obtain sorted results out of IndexedDB using different keys.

The conditions are:

1. There are 2 keys in IndexedDB, one is used for filtering and one is used for sorting
2. At the time of querying, the filtering key value is known, but the values delimiting the sorting key possible values are not known
3. The sorting key values may contain random numbers and letters

My solution consists of two things:

- A compound index with two keys: The filtering key and the sorting key. In my example I filter by *name* and sort by *id*:

  `objectStore.createIndex('nameId', ['name','id'], { unique: true });`
- In the query, I use that index with a lower and upper bound. Not an elegant solution because of the "0" appending:

  `objectStore.index('nameId').openCursor(window.IDBKeyRange.bound(['John'], ['John' + '0'], true, false));`

That works as expected, returning in my example:

```
 1. {"name":"John","id":13}
 2. {"name":"John","id":75}
 3. {"name":"John","id":77}
 4. {"name":"John","id":78}
 5. {"name":"John","id":88}
 6. {"name":"John","id":98}
 7. {"name":"John","id":99}
```

Is there a more elegant solution to achieve the same result?

The full example:

http://codepen.io/ncortines/pen/pjvgJB?editors=001

```js
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert('Your browser doesn\'t support a stable version of IndexedDB');
}

function log(text) {
 var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = text;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function addData(objectStore) {
 objectStore.put({ name: 'Paul', id: 45 });
   objectStore.put({ name: 'Paul', id: 56 });
   objectStore.put({ name: 'Paul', id: 43 });
   objectStore.put({ name: 'Paul', id: 36 });
   objectStore.put({ name: 'Paul', id: 10 });
   objectStore.put({ name: 'Paul', id: 93 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'John', id: 78 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'John', id: 77 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'John', id: 75 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'John', id: 98 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'John', id: 88 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'John', id: 13 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'John', id: 99 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'Patrick', id: 34 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'Patrick', id: 23 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'Patrick', id: 12 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'Patrick', id: 87 });
    objectStore.put({ name: 'Patrick', id: 02 });
}

var request = window.indexedDB.open('Test', 1);

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
 var db = event.target.result,
  objectStore = db.transaction('customers').objectStore('customers'),
  cursor = objectStore.index('nameId').openCursor(window.IDBKeyRange.bound(['John'], ['John' + '0'], true, false));

 cursor.onsuccess = function (event) {
        var cursor = event.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
         log(JSON.stringify(cursor.value));
         cursor.continue();
        }
        
    };
};
request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) {
   var db = event.target.result,
  objectStore = db.createObjectStore('customers', { keyPath: 'id' });

 objectStore.createIndex('nameId', ['name','id'], { unique: true });

 objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function (event) {
  var transaction = db.transaction('customers', 'readwrite'),
   objectStore = transaction.objectStore('customers');
  
  addData(objectStore);
 };
};
```

Comment: Without sorting it in code this will probably be the only solution for it

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention it, but another condition is no sorting or filtering using JavaScript after the fetch. Thanks @KristofDegrave

Comment: indexeddb only allows one index to use for filtering and sorting. All the rest you need to do your self. Mayby a little tip, if you need to sort or filter some more you can use webworkers so you don't block the UI thread

Comment: sure, there are many things that can be done in code, but I'd like to keep this strictly related to IndexedDB's API. Thanks!

Comment: That is how indexeddb filter and sort. There is nothing more in IDB, other than you can iterate another cursor in parallel. You can use `\uFFFF` instead of `0` or `['John', '\uFFFF']`.

Comment: Thanks @KyawTun. Yeah I guess "\uFFFF" is better option than "0"

Comment: Yep, that's all you can do. We've talked about introducing something like IDBKeyRange.forPrefix() for this scenario, with a "prollyfill" at: https://gist.github.com/inexorabletash/5462871

Comment: check this library http://dexie.org/